# On submitting a form, I am updating many db table with calculated data. but if network connection lost in between then how to handle this in laravel

Tags: connection

On submitting a form in laravel , I am updating many db tables with calculated data.but if network connection lost in between, then how to handle this in situation in laravel

I tried rollback transaction method but it is not working every time. This is not rolling back all the manipulation which is made in database. I am using mysql db with laravel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.